# .NET path manipulation library

Tags: .net, path

Does anyone know of any good library that abstracts the problem of path manipulation in a nice way? I'd like to be able to combine and parse paths with arbitrary separators ('/' or ':' for example) without reinventing the wheel.

It's a shame that `System.IO.Path` isn't more reusable.

Thanks

Comment: I think System.IO.Path works great. Do you have specific tasks that you need that it can't handle?

Comment: Can you use [Path.DirectorySeparatorChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar.aspx)?

Comment: @Espo: try reading the second sentence of my question.

Answer (score 1):

System.IO.Path.Combine will work great for many different types of paths:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx

System.IO.Path.Combine uses the current platform standard separators to combine paths. That means on Windows it uses "\" and on unix/linux (mono) it uses "/". Can you give some samples of what paths you are trying to combine and on what platform?

Comment: Afraid System.IO.Path does not help because the separator characters it uses and understands are predefined. As I stated, I need to use arbitrary separator characters such as ':' and '/'. Best I can do with System.IO.Path is convert my arbitrary characters to those it recognizes (such as '\') and then convert back again after. But that is a hacky solution at best.

Answer (score 1):

Check Patrick's library to handle path operations [link text](http://codebetter.com/blogs/patricksmacchia/archive/2007/10/18/a-free-library-to-handle-common-path-operation.aspx)

This is the [codeplex project](http://www.codeplex.com/FileDirectoryPath)

Comment: Thanks - that library looks useful, but it still doesn't allow a custom path separator to be specified. It just uses Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.

Answer (score 0):

You're describing regular expressions! Use that as the underpinning for what you need to do.

Comment: Sure, regular expressions will work and that is what I've used up until now. But they seem like overkill and are unlikely to perform as well as a dedicated path manipulation library. Afterall, System.IO.Path doesn't use regular expression in its implementation, does it?

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell what environment you might be using based off of your separators, but I have never seen a library like this before.

So using reflector and `System.IO.Path` as a basis it isn't difficult to reinvent the wheel.

- Create an instance of this class
- Supply your separator characters in the CTor
- Optionally change the `InvalidPathChars` if needed.

This is pretty much the code that is used by the framework so it should be just as fast or only a negligible difference. May or may not be faster than RegEx, it is probably worth a test though.

```
class ArbitraryPath
{
    private readonly char _directorySeparatorChar;
    private readonly char _altDirectorySeparatorChar;
    private readonly char _volumeSeparatorChar;

    public ArbitraryPath(char directorySeparatorChar, char altDirectorySeparatorChar, char volumeSeparatorChar)
    {
        _directorySeparatorChar = directorySeparatorChar;
        _altDirectorySeparatorChar = altDirectorySeparatorChar;
        _volumeSeparatorChar = volumeSeparatorChar;
    }

    public string Combine(string path1, string path2)
    {
        if ((path1 == null) || (path2 == null))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException((path1 == null) ? "path1" : "path2");
        }
        CheckInvalidPathChars(path1);
        CheckInvalidPathChars(path2);
        if (path2.Length == 0)
        {
            return path1;
        }
        if (path1.Length == 0)
        {
            return path2;
        }
        if (IsPathRooted(path2))
        {
            return path2;
        }

        char ch = path1[path1.Length - 1];
        if (ch != _directorySeparatorChar && ch != _altDirectorySeparatorChar && ch != _volumeSeparatorChar)
        {
            return (path1 + _directorySeparatorChar + path2);
        }
        return (path1 + path2);
    }

    public bool IsPathRooted(string path)
    {
        if (path != null)
        {
            CheckInvalidPathChars(path);
            int length = path.Length;
            if (length >= 1 && (path[0] == _directorySeparatorChar || path[0] == _altDirectorySeparatorChar) || length >= 2 && path[1] == _volumeSeparatorChar)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    internal static void CheckInvalidPathChars(string path)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < path.Length; i++)
        {
            int num2 = path[i];
            if (num2 == 0x22 || num2 == 60 || num2 == 0x3e || num2 == 0x7c || num2 < 0x20)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Argument_InvalidPathChars");
            }
        }
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid [you'll have to implement a path class yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026302/is-there-a-class-for-holding-a-file-system-path), as I did. It gives the following advantages:

- you can profit from type safety
- you can override operator/, which makes concatenation easier
- you can add convenience member functions such as GetParentPath() and GetLeafPart()