# Good reasons to pass paths as strings instead of using DirectoryInfo/FileInfo

Tags: .net, string, directory

In my new code I am *not* using strings to pass directory paths or file names.  Instead I am using DirectoryInfo and FileInfo as they seem to encapsulate a lot of information.

I have seen a lot of code that uses strings to pass directory information then they "split" and "mid" and "instr" in long incomprehensible statements until they get the part of the directory they are looking for.

Is there any good reason to pass paths as strings?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general, I think keeping the information in FileInfo/DirectoryInfo is better.  There is a lot of useful functionality in these classes, as well as a lot of safety involved in that it's much easier to check for existence of a file, see the originally specified file, etc.

The only place where I would (potentially) pass a path as as a string instead of using FileInfo and DirectoryInfo would if the path was going to be passed across AppDomains or between processes, etc.

FileInfo and DirectoryInfo both work fine across AppDomain boundaries (since they're Serializable), but they have a fair amount more overhead in this situation.  If things are going back and forth a lot, it could have an impact.

I would stick with FileInfo and DirectoryInfo in this case, though, unless I found that there was a noticeable problem during my profiling, and I was trying to reduce the amount of serialized data.  If I didn't run into performance issues, I'd stick with using these classes, as they provide a lot of safety and functionality.

Comment: Note that you will need to create a new FileInfo/DirectoryInfo if the file has changed its existance or modified timestamps.

Answer (score 7):

`DirectoryInfo` and `FileInfo` are awful heavy for passing around if all you need is a path. I'd be more concerned about the "split and mid and instr" junk. Learn the ways of:

Path.GetFileName
Path.GetDirectoryName
Path.Combine
etc...

Those are from the `System.IO.Path` class, btw.

Comment: Remember, when you're passing an instance into a function, it's passing a copy of the reference, not a copy of the entire object! So all you're really passing is copy of a pointer...

Comment: I believe the issue isn't how many bytes are passed around, but rather the overhead of using FileInfo/DirectoryInfo, which has to probe the file in a variety of ways to cache information about it.

Answer (score 6):

Once the path is in an application (i.e. not in a plain text configuration file), no, there isn't a good reason.

The only time (I can think of) it could be useful is when interoperating with code that only accepts paths as strings.

Answer (score 2):

One significant difference between path string and FileInfo to bear in mind, which can be summarized in the tests below:

**A FileInfo reflects the info about the file as of when it was instantiated** - it can be deleted/modified and the FileInfo won't reflect that.

```
[TestMethod]
        public void TestFileInfo()
        {
            var path = @"C:\Users\bjarmuz\Desktop\aybabtu.txt";
            File.WriteAllText(path, "All your base are belong to us!");
            var file = new FileInfo(path);

            Assert.IsTrue(file.Exists);
            File.Delete(file.FullName);
            Assert.IsTrue(file.Exists);
            Assert.IsFalse(File.Exists(file.FullName));
        }

  [TestMethod]
        public void TestFileInfo()
        {
            var path = @"C:\Users\bjarmuz\Desktop\aybabtu.txt";
            File.WriteAllText(path, "All your base are belong to us!");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            var file = new FileInfo(path);
            var date = DateTime.UtcNow;

            Assert.IsTrue(file.LastWriteTimeUtc< date);

            File.WriteAllText(path, "No!");
            Assert.IsTrue(File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(file.FullName)> date);

            Assert.IsFalse(file.LastWriteTimeUtc > date);
        }
```

This can be somewhat misleading, and if your code passes around FileInfos instead of strings, you might see incorrect results for the properties such as `Exists` or `Last[..]Time` - which would not happen if you'd use the `File.Get[...]()` methods.

**However, on the other hand,** you should not rely on the File.Exists() method either - because the file can be created/deleted just after you run the tests. Proper way for that is to NOT do this check, and rather accept that it can throw the IO exception (and be ready to handle it properly). More info in this great article https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/

Also, a significant 'upside' of FileInfo/DirectoryInfo is that it protects your method (and the method consumers) from this:

```
void SaveEntity(Entity theThing, string path)
{
    //now, based on the signature, you don't know whether you need file path or directory path

}

//void SaveEntity(Entity theThing, DirectoryInfo path) {}
//void SaveEntity(Entity theThing, FileInfo path) {}
```

Comment: Right, you need to be aware of this fact and call the FileInfo."Refresh" method if you desire up-to-date values.

Answer (score 1):

I think you do need a class to encapsulate a file or directory path, instead of using raw strings and manipulating them using the static System.IO.Path class. However, [I don't find DirectoryInfo and FileInfo suitable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026991/combining-a-directoryinfo-and-a-fileinfo-path), because they seem to be intended more for doing file/directory manipulations instead of path operations. If you make a custom class for path manipulation, you can provide [more user friendly path manipulation functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52071/net-path-manipulation-library/3677449#3677449).

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered problems when passing FileInfo to DMZ's. As far as I can see - correct me if i'm wrong - FileInfo performs a permission check when deserializing and that won't work from DMZ and result in 'path not found'. Create and pass a custom object with the data you  instead.

Answer (score 0):

I found out a good reason to not use either.
At the end of the day a Path is Type that usually is represented though a string, but its not a string itself, it has some behaviour as explained [in this video (Just check the few seconds after seconds 60)](https://youtu.be/_TMZsPjoGJA?t=63).

That video itself provides a good solution for file path management that is a good start for whatever other behaviour you are looking for on a Path.

The only drawback would be some memory overhead on extremely high performance environments, but if you are not creating hundreds of path objects, there is no reason to not use the following code on most of cases:

```
//This class provides all the rules for your application about how to handle a path as a value
public record FilePath
{
    public string Path { get; }
    
    public FilePath (string path) => 
        Path = 
            string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (path) 
                ? throw new ArgumentException ("path cannot be null or empty") :
            System.IO.Path.GetInvalidPathChars().Intersect (path).Any()
                ? throw new ArgumentException ("Path contains illegal characters")
                : System.IO.Path.GetFullPath (path.Trim());
            
    public override string ToString() => Path;
    
    //Note on linux environments you would make it case sensitive
    public virtual bool Equals (FilePath? other) => 
        (Path).Equals (other?.Path, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

    public override int GetHashCode() => Path.ToLowerInvariant().GetHashCode();

    public static implicit operator FilePath (string name) => new FilePath (name);

    public FileInfo GetInfo() => new FileInfo (Path);

    public FilePath Combine (params string[] paths) =>
        System.IO.Path.Combine (paths.Prepend (Path).ToArray());
}
```

Credits to [Joe Albahari](https://www.albahari.com/), checkout the video for more interesting things about C#.

Sample extracted from [LinQPad 7](https://www.linqpad.net/) source code samples.