# .NET: System.IO.Path

Tags: .net, path

Given a string that is to a directory, how can I make sure there's a closing `\` character? For example, `C:\foo` is a directory, and so is `C:\foo\`. Is there a `System.IO.Path` method that ensures there's a ending `\`?

Comment: Remember, "/" is also a valid separator on Windows (well, except for `cmd.exe` and `command.com`) .

Answer (score 5):

```
if (!filename.EndsWith(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar))
    filename += Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
```

Comment: You might also want to check for Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar

Answer (score 3):

Presumably you want to append a separator so that you can subsequently append filenames using string concatenation.

In which case Kyle Rozendo's initial advice is sound: consider whether you really need to do that.  If you always append filenames using Path.Combine, you don't need to care whether your path has a trailing separator.

If you still want to do this, you have an edge case to consider.  The path "D:" is a valid relative path that references the current working directory on the D: drive.  Appending a separator will change this meaning to reference the root directory on the D: drive.  Do you really want this?  I'm guessing not.  So I would special case this thus:

```
public static string AppendSeparator(string path)
{
    if (path == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("path");
    if (path.Length == 0) return path;
    if (path[path.Length - 1] == Path.VolumeSeparatorChar) return path;
    if (path[path.Length - 1] == Path.DirectorySeparatorChar) return path;
    if (path[path.Length - 1] == Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar) return path;
    return path + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
}
```

You can then use this as follows - the last example converts the input path to an absolute path before appending the separator:

```
path = AppendSeparator(@"C:\SomePath\");
path = AppendSeparator(@"C:\SomePath");
path = AppendSeparator(@"D:");
path = AppendSeparator(Path.GetFullPath("D:"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hay,
what about using this condition

`if (s.IndexOf('\\') == s.Length - 1)`

where s is your path string "amr\" will give true "amr" will give false

Comment: IndexOf gives the first apperance of the searched string, quite likely the one after the drive.

Comment: You should rather use s.EndsWith or s.LastIndexOf. But EndsWith will work with zero-length strings.

Comment: You should ideally check for Path.DirectorySeparatorChar and Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar rather than a hardwired backslash.

Answer (score 0):

[I think you need to write a custom path class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667318/good-reasons-to-pass-paths-as-strings-instead-of-using-directoryinfo-fileinfo/3677556#3677556).