# Is there a class for holding a file system path?

Tags: .net

In the .NET base class library there is a class System.IO.Path for doing common operations on strings representing a file system path. However, what I need is **a class that encapsulates a path** instead, so I get type-safety and a possibly shorter notation of path operations. I'm thinking of a .NET equivalent of [C++ Boost's](http://www.boost.org/) path class. Does such a class exist?

**Update**: I'm not necessarily looking for a class that can hold **both file and directory paths**. However, as a file system path can be used for pointing to both, I find it obvious that same class can be used.

**Conclusion**: *DirectoryInfo* and *FileInfo* come close to what I'm looking for. However, they seem to be intended as a representation of a file or directory, rather than a file or directory path. This makes it **difficult to do path operations**, such as [combining a directory path and a relative file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026991/combining-a-directoryinfo-and-a-fileinfo-path), so I think I'll write a class that encapsulates a path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such class as part of the .NET Framework. I suggest you write your own, perhaps based on StringBuilder and the Path class.

Comment: Doesn't the DirectoryInfo do this? :-)

Comment: Does it work for paths that don't exist? If he meant to limit himself to actual directories, then I wish he'd update the question to say so.

Comment: It has an Exists property and a Create method, so yes it works on directories that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 9):

You are looking for the [`System.IO.DirectoryInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) class.

The `DirectoryInfo` class derives from the abstract [`[FileSystemInfo]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.aspx) class and you also have the [`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) class that describes files.

Comment: Indeed, this seems to be appropriate for directory paths. Is there also a class that can hold a path to a file?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your specific problem, you could to use [`Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class as it can also to represent local addresses.

But, as [Rune said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026302/is-there-a-class-for-holding-a-file-system-path/2026314#2026314) (+1) you probably should go with `DirectoryInfo`

Answer (score 0):

I think the mindset in .NET is not to bind a file path to a protocol.

For example, File class is used statically.
The identity of a file path is passed around as a string, and then when you need to find out, you do the static method File.exists(pathstring).

I prefer the mindset in .NET over Java's having an instantiable File class. Because once you have an instantiable File class, everybody expects a File object to be passed around.

Normally, a file identity is best passed around as a string because it goes through multiple string mutations and checking and comparison, where most comparisons/mutation is best and efficiently done thro regex. Having a file identity passed around as a File object sucks up cpu because you have to extract the string and if modified you have to reinstantiate a new File object.

Frequently, in Java, I find that I have to convert a File object to string back and forth and back and forth incessantly, because other programmers or library providers have an obsessive/compulsive love affair with the File class.